# Difference between ModelState.IsValid, TryValidateModel() and ValidateModel() in mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between `ModelState.IsValid`, `TryValidateModel()` and `ValidateModel()` in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ModelState.IsValid:
```

Indicates if there are any errors in the current view model. It will not call any validation functions. It is like a flag.

```
ValidateModel():
```

From [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.validatemodel%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

> Validates the specified model instance.When a model is being
>   validated, all validators for all properties are run if at least one
>   form input is bound to a model property.

```
TryValidateModel():
```

From [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryvalidatemodel%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

> The TryValidateModel is like the ValidateModel method except that the
>   TryValidateModel method does not throw an
>   InvalidOperationExceptionexception if the model validation fails.